# MongoDB query updateOne doesn't find match

Tags: arrays, mongodb, list

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

The database intention:

```
category : {
    name : category_name, subcategory : [{
        name : subcategory_name, skill : [{
            name : skill_name
        }]
    }]
}
```

Category have an array of subcategories, which also have an array of skills.

So I can have many subcategories into a category, and each subcategory can have many skills.

The following query creates the category "Web development" with 2 subcategories, "Frontend" and "Backend", with their respective skills

```
db.skills.insertOne({ category : { cat_name : "Web development", subcategory : [{ subcat_name : "Frontend", skills : [{ skill_name : "Angular", skill_name : "Css"}]}, { subcat_name : "Backend", skills : [{ skill_name : "Nodejs", skill_name : "Express" }]}]}})
```

The problem: the following query returns { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 } which means that it didn't find the category "Web development"

```
db.skills.updateOne( { category : { cat_name : "Web development" }}, { $set: { category : { cat_name : "Not web development" }}} )
```

Same for the next query, it didn't find the subcategory

```
db.skills.updateOne( { subcategory : { subcat_name : "Frontend" }}, { $push: { skills : { skill_name : "SASS" }}} )
```

db.skills.find() returns the first insertOne but doesn't have the first skills, "Angular" from frontend subcategory and "Nodejs" from the backend subcategory, which makes no sense:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62effb72d6fbc7d2a7d756d5"), "category" : { "cat_name" : "Web development", "subcategory" : [ { "subcat_name" : "Frontend", "skills" : [ { "skill_name" : "Css" } ] }, { "subcat_name" : "Backend", "skills" : [ { "skill_name" : "Express" } ] } ] } }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't duplicate field names like this `skills : [{ skill_name : "Nodejs", skill_name : "Express" }]`.

Comment: But aren't those 2 different index in the array? Then I should do this? `skills : { skill_name : [  "Nodejs", "Express" ]}`

Comment: I can't decide on your data model without knowing a lot more ... expected queries, etc.

Comment: The expected queries are just add new skills, subcategories and categories. The end move will follow this: if category and subcategory names exists, insert the skill. If category exists but subcategory not, then add the subcategory and then the skill. If nothing exists then create the category with the subcategory and the skill.

Comment: Then perhaps just an array of skills within the proper category/subcategory will be fine.  You may want an array of objects instead, if say, you also want to insert/query something like `"skillLevel"`, etc.

Comment: I just need the skill name, subcategory name and category name, which are send by a form, but the problem related to the question persist, I don't know how to make the query work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your schema a bit to what I think you intend to do, here are a couple of `update` commands that show how you can accomplish what you want.  Note the use of "dot notation" and `"arrayFilters"`.  These aren't the only ways to do this, just one of the ways.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "categories.cat_name": "Web development"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "categories": {
      "cat_name": "Not web development"
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_LaaYm8BBGW).

Here's how you can `"$push"` a new skill.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "categories.cat_name": "Web development"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "categories.$[catElem].subcategories.$[subcatElem].skills": "SASS"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {"catElem.cat_name": "Web development"},
    {"subcatElem.subcat_name": "Frontend"}
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AyXhVZC5Prb).

Comment: Thanks, it solves all the problems.